# function to go to website if button is ON

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a simple ON/OFF button.
i just want to go to a link (in the background if possible) when the button is ON , and a different link when it is OFF 
pls help me in javascript too as im a beginner in it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" onclick="javascript:location.href='www.google.com" >
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add an onchange listener and direct the user based on the checked status of the check box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myonoffswitch2').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      window.location="url to site 1";
    }
    else{
      window.location="url to site 2";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2">
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">Check</label>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" onclick="javascript:location.href='https://www.google.com';" >
```

//this code for button is on but what do you mean by off when your button is on then your page is redirect